# Trim an ordered dict to the last x items

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to trim an ordered dict to the last x items.

I have the following code, which works but doesn't seem very pythonic.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict()
# SNIP: POPULATE DICT HERE!
d = collections.OrderedDict(d.items()[-3:])
```

Comment: For starters, it wouldn't work on python3 as `d.items()` is a generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works a bit faster:

```
for k in range(len(d) - x) : data.popitem(last = False)
```

Not really sure how pythonic it is though.

Benefits include not having to cast create a new OrderedDict object, and not having to look at keys or items.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to trim the dictionary in place, then you can pop the offending items:

```
for k in d.keys()[:-3]:
    d.pop(k)
```

(On python 3, you'll need to convert `.keys()` to a list).

If you're wishing to create a new `OrderedDict`, then its not clear quite what is "unpythonic" about your current approach.